# Salesforce Command line Dataloader - Passing Parameters to Process-conf.xml ?

Tags: data-loader, automation, commandline

My currrent situation is I have process-conf.xml, with multiple environments and multiple orgs eg. dev and QA
Then an entry for each Object(Account, Opportunity) that I may be inserting for Automation.

```
<bean id="insert-account-dev3" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"  singleton="false">
    <description>Insert Account Records used by automated regression
        tests.</description>
    <property name="name" value="insert-account-dev3" />
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com" />
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value="<b>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxx.dev</b>" />
            <entry key="sfdc.password"
                value="<b>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</b>" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="delete-account-dev3" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"  singleton="false">
    <description>Delete Account records used by automated regression
        tests.</description>
    <property name="name" value="delete-account-dev3" />
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com" />
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value="<b>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxx.dev</b>" />
            <entry key="sfdc.password"
                value="<b>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</b>" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

    <bean id="insert-account-QA" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"    singleton="false">
    <description>Insert Account Records used by automated regression
        tests.</description>
    <property name="name" value="insert-account-QA" />
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com" />
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value="<b>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxx.QA</b>" />
            <entry key="sfdc.password"
                value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="delete-account-QA" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"    singleton="false">
    <description>Delete Account records used by automated regression
        tests.</description>
    <property name="name" value="delete-account-QA" />
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com" />
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value="<b>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxx.QA</b>" />
            <entry key="sfdc.password"
                value="<b>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</b>" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>


etc....
```

currently what I find at the moment to be a problem is if passwords expire or change, I will then have to change my process-conf in multiple places.

Is there anyway to Parameterize, it perhaps 
having a seperate file like so

```
devUserName=xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.dev
devToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
qaUserName=xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.QA
qaToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
etc.(Other Orgs)
```

Then having beans

```
<bean id="insert-account-dev" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"   singleton="false">
    <description>Insert Account Records used by automated regression
        tests.</description>
    <property name="name" value="insert-account-dev" />
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com" />
            <entry key="sfdc.username" value="**devUserName**" />
            <entry key="sfdc.password"
                value="**devToken**" />
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Fyi some stuff I did with Ant a long time ago [Scripting the Apex Data Loader via Ant](https://force201.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/scripting-the-apex-data-loader-via-ant/).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should absolutely be making use of the config.properties file - [it's best practice](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/tutorial-of-command-line-dataloader-salesforce/). You can then add all of your UN and PW to it and adjust the key's accordingly.

## project/config/config.properties

```
sfdc.endpoint=https://login.salesforce.com
sfdc.username=................
process.encryptionKeyFile=C:\\Users\\gazaino\\Projects\\DL\\key.txt
sfdc.password.int=...................
sfdc.password.test=..................
sfdc.password=.....................
sfdc.debugMessages=true
process.enableLastRunOutput=false
sfdc.loadBatchSize=200
sfdc.timeoutSecs=600
sfdc.extractionRequestSize=500
```

There should be a single `config.properties` file located in the same path as your `process-conf.xml` file. You can see it includes more than just UN and PW. You can also see I'm storing my DEV and UAT server information as well. Depending on the server you go to, adjust the parameter as necessary.

---

### project/config/process-conf.xml

```
...
<!-- ENROLLMENT CODE EXTRACT -->
<bean id="enrollmentCodeExtract" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">
  <description>Extract enrollment code records that don't have their requirement fields set.</description>
    <property name="name" value="enrollmentCodeExtract"/>
    <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Enrollment_Code__c"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="C:\Users\gazaino\Projects\DL\enrollmentCode\log\enrollmentCodeExtract.log"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="SELECT Id FROM Enrollment_Code__c WHERE Background_Check_Drug_Screen_Required__c=null OR Client_On_Boarding_Docs_Required__c=null"/>
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="C:\Users\gazaino\Projects\DL\enrollmentCode\enrollmentCodeExtract.sdl"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Users\gazaino\Projects\DL\enrollmentCode\enrollmentCodeExtract.csv"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
...
```

The process-conf.xml file still contains key parameters that are required for that specific bean, but it pulls parameters which are generalized and can be used across multiple beans.

---

## CLI Execution

```
cd dataloader/bin
process.bat project/config enrollmentCodeExtract
```

1. Navigate to the bin directory of your dataloader
2. execute `process.bat` with argument 1 being the path to your `process-conf.xml` file and argument 2 being the name of the bean you wish to run.

---

This [KB Article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line) has a great explanation of where you should store specific parameters:

> **Property value interactions**
>
> There are three places where you can define property-value pairs -
>
> **The command line**
>
> The command line requires two parameters - the configuration directory and the name of the process. You can also include any other property value pairs that could be listed in the process-conf.xml file. Any property-value pairs included as part of the command line are used in place of any other specifications in the other files.
>
> **config.properties**
>
> File located in the configuration folder, which can contain any property-value pairs. Any property-value pairs listed in this file are used in place of their specification in the process-conf.xml file.
>
> **process-conf.xml**
>
> File that contains properties for all processes. Each process has it's own section in the file. To invoke a particular process defined in process-conf.xml pass the name of the process in the command via the process.name parameter. For example; jar -cp DataLoader.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=conf com.salesforce.lexiloader.process.ProcessRunner process.name=csvUpsertAccount. Otherwise, the process-conf.xml file will not be referenced and all required Data Loader values will need to be entered in the config.properties file.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_params.htm) is a link to all of the Data Loader configuration parameters; can't hurt to provide more info.

Comment: Perfect, looking at this before I thought that it was only explicit fields that could be passed in from the config.properties (e.g sfdc.username) 

Then just on passing them to the process-conf.xml 
How do I do that now

Comment: The config.properties file is loaded first. If the bean in your process-conf.xml file has a property, it overrides what is specified in the config.properties file. So if you build the config.properties file with you credentials you just exclude the arguments from your beans. I'll update my answer shortly to be more descriptive with that information.

Comment: Apologies. I'm still a little confused

Comment: also is there an explicit way to specify the location of the config.properties files

Comment: I don't believe you can specify where the `config.properties` file lives. It should be in the same directory as your `process-conf.xml` file and there should only be 1 `config.properties` file. I updated my answer to reflect this. I use the approach of modifying the `config.properties` file to change environments. As mentioned in the KB article in my answer, you could pass property values into the CLI if you want to control the properties with each execution, but then you are passing your credentials in each time. Please specify what else you have confusion on, so I can try to help.

Comment: I think all I need to do now is just how do I specify the values I want to use in the process-conf from the config.properties file, sorry for the amount of questions, I really appreciate the help

Comment: @ThomasWoodhouse the values are specified based on their absence from the `process-conf.xml` file. If that file is missing the Username and Passsword, dataloader will look at the `config.properties` file. If the UN and PW are missing from the config file as well, it errors (unless you've set it up to pass in from the CLI). By simply not having the value specified in your bean, dataloader will look to the config file. IF both files have a parameter, it uses the value from the `process-conf.xml` file.

Comment: I think i get you now  
so if i have my config.properties file like here  

  `sfdc.username.dev3=XXXXXXXXX.com.dev3`  
    `sfdc.password.dev3=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`  


i can then change my process-conf.xml from this  

  `<entry key="sfdc.username" value=xxxxxxxxxxx@xxx.com.dev3" />`  
    `<entry key="sfdc.password" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"" />`  


To this  
  `<entry key="sfdc.username.dev3" />`  
    `<entry key="sfdc.password.dev3" />`

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I'm saying. Dataloader only takes keys of `sfdc.username` and `sfdc.password`. I store my other credentials with the server name appended to the key for easy recognition and remove the suffix when I want to work on that server. If you have the `sfdc.username` key in `config.properties` leave it out of all of your beans in `process-conf.xml` - same goes for `sfdc.password`. Leave those two files in the same directory, and you should be good to go. The `config.properties` file becomes a repository for your credentials.