# force cli query for more then 2000 records

Tags: soql, query

When using the force cli query.  It works great and is very fast, but I want to get all records and it only grabs 2000 records.  I think that it is limited by soql.  How do I get all the data on an object using the cli force tool.

For example:

```
force query select Id, Name from Account --format:csv > Account.csv
```

This returns 2000 records, but I have many 1000 more.  How do I get them all.  Is there a trick or did I miss something in the documentation?

Comment: The CLI is intended to act just as the GUI. When you run your query through the GUI, do you get the same result? Also, I would strongly suggest using the `config.properties` and `process-conf.xml` files. It make building out your queries easier in the long run. You can get more info in my other [SE post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112607/salesforce-command-line-dataloader-passing-parameters-to-process-conf-xml/112609#112609)

Comment: Yes the query in the GUI is the same.  I am not sure how to query for more records in the GUI either.  I will need to figure that out and what the config.properties and process-conf.xml files does.  I will look at your post. thanks...  Any practical examples would be great

Comment: Based on your query, there is nothing limiting it. Why do you say there are 1000 more records not being queried? It could potentially be sharing rules. It could also be the 1000 additional records are 'soft-deleted' (i.e. recycle bin), and you need to leverage the `extract all` [command](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_operations.htm) - available in both CLI and GUI.

Comment: I am using the [force cli](https://force-cli.heroku.com/) on a Mac and not the dataloader with windows.   I have a total of 5345 rows.  I seem to only get 2000 rows when I use the query in the Force CLI.  There must be a way to extract all.  I just don't see any documentation or examples using this tool on a MAC.

Comment: Ahh, got it - I keep forgetting the force CLI is out there and supports queries. Sorry for the mix up. I haven't played around with it, so can't give much insight. I would suggest pagination, but I just saw your other [post on SE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719684/force-cli-query-of-salesforce-object-with-more-than-2000-records). If the records are visible through the pagination query, I would suspect it's a batching issue with the tool. Not too sure how to fix that, as you mentioned it would most likely be a script that needs to execute the query several times.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The documentation for the force CLI is very weak.  I can do it using [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RForcecom), but it is slow and I was looking at a way to speed it up.  Unfortunately I am going to have to use the tool I have and works but is slow.  I may need to learn Apex but I am doing a data project and don't want to make it more complex than I have too.